# Redux componentDidUpdate get previous state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I refactored Redux into my code, but can't figure out how to get the previous state.
I need this state for my componentDidUpdate lifecycle method so that I can call other methods without getting trapped in an infinite loop.

```
// when component re-renders
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
 // if the current page changes, or the search term changes.
 if(prevState.currentPage !== this.props.bucketlistState.currentPage || 
  prevState.searchTerm !== this.props.bucketlistState.searchTerm) {
  this.getBucketlists();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`prevState` is the second parameter to `componentDidUpdate`, The first parameter is `prevProps`

```
// when component re-renders
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 // if the current page changes, or the search term changes.
 if(prevState.currentPage !== this.props.bucketlistState.currentPage || 
  prevState.searchTerm !== this.props.bucketlistState.searchTerm) {
  this.getBucketlists();
 }
}
```

Check the **[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)**

**Syntax:**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
```

PS: Its an antipattern to have a state that is directly derivable from props. You should instead directly use props and compare them in componentDidUpdate like

```
// when component re-renders
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 // if the current page changes, or the search term changes.
 if(prevProps.bucketlistState.currentPage !== this.props.bucketlistState.currentPage || 
  prevProps.bucketlistState.searchTerm !== this.props.bucketlistState.searchTerm) {
  this.getBucketlists();
 }
}
```

and since you are using props only for comparison, a more suited place before **v16.3** of React would be to do it is the `componentWillReceiveProps` function, however this function is likely to be removed in future major React release and it is expected for you to use `componentDidUpdate`. For more information please check

[`Can getDerivedStateFromProps be used as an alternative to componentWillReceiveProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599656/can-getderivedstatefromprops-be-used-as-an-alternative-to-componentwillreceivepr/49599776#49599776)

```
// when component re-renders
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
 // if the current page changes, or the search term changes.
 if(nextProps.bucketlistState.currentPage !== this.props.bucketlistState.currentPage || 
  nextProps.bucketlistState.searchTerm !== this.props.bucketlistState.searchTerm) {
  this.getBucketlists(nextProps);
 }
}
```

Comment: @ckwaga why do you store props currentPage in state

Comment: The currentPage is used by other components.

Comment: @ckwagaba, even if it is used by other componets, you can just directly use it from props and pass the same down to its children rather than keeping a state

Comment: Note:
    These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code:
        ``UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()``
        ``UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()``

Comment: @JanakaPushpakumara, componentDidUpdate is not a legacy method and also componentWillReceiveProps need not be renamed till v17 as the current name will continue to work.

Answer (score 2):

[`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) takes two parameters the first the previous props and the second the previous state

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps , prevState) {
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Just did that, but to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I gotta use prevProps, instead of prevState, since state from the store is returned as props!!!

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps , prevState) {
    // if the current page changes, or the search term changes.
    if(prevProps.bucketlistState.currentPage !== this.props.bucketlistState.currentPage || prevProps.bucketlistState.searchTerm !== this.props.bucketlistState.searchTerm) {
        this.getBucketlists();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are doing such a check, a better place is the componentWillReceiveProps function, check my answer

Comment: There is no need to repeat the code you have received from other answers, just accept the one that helped you the most as an answer

Comment: Sure! Saw the answer later, though!!