# Can getDerivedStateFromProps be used as an alternative to componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

> getDerivedStateFromProps is being added as a safer alternative to the legacy componentWillReceiveProps.

This is what the 16.3 doc says. Is there anything more to this lifecycle or is it just a name change?

Comment: https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b - It's `static` and returns instead of setting state

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is not just a name change to `componentWillReceiveProps`. It's a static method that is called after a component is instantiated or before it receives new props, unlike `componentWillReceiveProps` which was not called on initial render.

> Return an object to update state in response to prop changes.
>
> Return null to indicate no change to state.

Static lifecycle methods are introduced to prevent unsafe access of instance properties.

The purpose of `getDerivedStateFromProps` is to only update the state based on props change and not take actions like API call or function call based on `prevProps` that could be done. All of these could be done in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function which is safe because even if the change was done in `componentWillReceiveProps` the data would arrive after render and most often you would trigger another re-render, which could well be done in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

You can refer to **[this RFC](https://github.com/bvaughn/rfcs/blob/7042a2abcbdc90b4a7784ea6a753ce9abac169d9/text/0000-static-lifecycle-methods.md)** to understand more about why this change was made.