# Using lifecycle method with redux versus checking prop state in render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Is there anything wrong with this flow in redux? I change isAuthenticated in my reducer like so

```
export function userReducer(state=initState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case AUTH_SUCCESS:
      return { 
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true
      }
      //...
      //...
  }
}
```

so in my render I check isAuthenticated if equal to true I redirect the user to login.

```
@connect(state => state.user, {loginUser})
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    const { email, password } = this.state
    this.props.login(email, password)
  }

  render(){
    const { email, password } = this.state

    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.user.isAuthenticated && <Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />}

        <Form input={{email, password}} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginForm
```

Another way is I can make the render method cleaner, I use componentWillRecieiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.user.isAuthenticated !== this.props.user.isAuthenticated && nextProps.user.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.replace('/dashboard')
  }
}
```

Which one is appropriate and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your methods are equivalent since, `Redirect` also replaces the current history stack and so does `this.props.history.replace()`. You can use anyone of the methods.

Also considering that React wants to deprecate the `componentWillReceiveProps` from `v17` onwards you are better of using `componentDidUpdate` for the same

However `componentDidUpdate` here has a slight disadvantage here that for a fraction of a second `Form` will be visible and then redirect will happen which might be a bad user experience.

So consider future development in React, you might use the `Redirect` approach instead of doing prop comparison and using `history.replace()`

Comment: componentDidUpdate fire if state changed, why catch props change with componentDidUpdate? has it changed?

Comment: componentDidUpdate is fired on both props or state change, and from v16.3.0 its recommended to spit logic of componentWillReceiveProps between componentDidUpdate and getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599656/can-getderivedstatefromprops-be-used-as-an-alternative-to-componentwillreceivepr/49599776#49599776

Comment: in my login case is it good to use getDerivedStateFromProps? I tried it it won't fire.

Comment: @MadelineRies, can you please tell me what is your exact version of React

Comment: "react": "^16.2.0"

Comment: @MadelineRies getDerivedStateFromProps is only available from v16.3.0 onwards. Also its recommended to use getDerivedStateFromProps only for state update

Comment: oh I see, so I'll use <Redirect /> then. But I notice there's a flickering issue like you said when I use componentDidUpdate.

Comment: @MadelineRies, yes and hence Redirect is the preferred method

Answer (score 1):

They are both valid ways, except `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated in react v16.3 so it would be better to use `componentDidUpdate`. And I would simplify logic as follows:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.user.isAuthenticated !== this.props.user.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.replace('/dashboard')
  }
}
```

There is one difference though, that with `Redirect` you don't have to create class component but you can use it in stateless component and it doesn't even have to be inside `Route` or connected `withRouter`.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ isLogged }) => (
  <div>
    {isLogged <Redirect to="/path" />}
    <div>something</div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is not deprecated in v16 or v16.3.0

Comment: componentDidUpdate will fire if prop changed?

Comment: @MadelineRies will get fired after props had changed.

Comment: but I tried `componentDidUpdate` I saw a flickering issue before redirect, it doesn't happens using `<Redirect />` in render.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, they're both valid.

Just from a react point of view, a login component should handle exactly that - logging in.

I would expect a higher component than the login page (the app perhaps), to do the logic of whether to display the Login form, or to redirect. E.g. something like this:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class App {
  render() {
    if (this.props.user.isAuthenticated && this.props.location === '/login') {
      return <Redirect to={'/dashboard'} />;
    }
    return (<div>
      REST OF APP HERE
    </div>);
  }
}

export default withRouter(props => <App {...props}/>);
```

The benefit here is you can easily test your login form, as well as compose it within other components really easily. Your routing concerns are effectively global, and those can live up at the top with your app.

Comment: @MadelineRies there is a difference. Presumably you have in your App class a set of routes, where one of them points to your LoginForm. Hoisting the logic of redirecting from outside the LoginForm to the App has the same difference as hoisting state from a child component to a parent component in the general react sense