# React with Redux: Child component does not rerender after props have changed (even though they are not shallow equal)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rerender

I'm building an app with React Native using Redux for the state management. I will post my code for all the involved components and the reducer down below, but since that is going to be much, let me describe the problem in a few sentences first.

I have an immutable reducer for my objects called 'waitercalls'. I have a screen (`HomeScreen`) that renders two components. Each component is a [`<FlatList />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) of objects. The objects (`waitercalls`) are given to them via props by it's parent (`HomeScreen`). `HomeScreen` is connected to Redux via React-Redux' `connect()` and gets the objects ('waitercalls') via a selector created with [Re-Select](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).

The left list's items can be pressed and upon press dispatch an event to the reducer. Here comes the problem. When the left list's item are pressed, the left list correctly updates (calls `render()`). The right list though does not re-render, even though it gets the same props.

Why does the left list rerender, but the right list not? The reducer is immutable, the selector is too and even the length of the list changes from one to zero which should eliminate the possibility of a shallow equal.

And now for the code:

waitercallsReducer:

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const initialState = {};

const waitercallsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.payload && action.payload.entities && action.payload.entities.waitercalls) {
    return {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload.entities.waitercalls
    };
  } else {
    return state;
  }
};

export default waitercallsReducer;

export const getAllWaitercallsNormalizedSelector = state => state.waitercalls;
export const getAllWaitercallsSelector = createSelector(
  getAllWaitercallsNormalizedSelector,
  waitercalls => Object.values(waitercalls)
);

export const getAllActiveWaitercallsSelector = createSelector(
  getAllWaitercallsSelector,
  waitercalls => waitercalls.filter(waitercall => !waitercall.done)
);
```

Action creators:

```
import { setValues } from "../core/core";

// feature name
export const WAITERCALLS = "[Waitercalls]";

// action creators
export const setValues = (values, type) => ({
  type: `SET ${type}`,
  payload: values,
  meta: { feature: type }
});
export const setWaitercalls = waitercalls => setValues(waitercalls, WAITERCALLS);
```

HomeScreen:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// ... I've omitted all the imports so that it's shorter

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  // ... I've omitted navigationOptions and propTypes

  render() {
    const {
      checkins,
      customChoiceItems,
      menuItemPrices,
      menuItems,
      orders,
      pickedRestaurant,
      tables,
      waitercalls
    } = this.props;
    console.log("Rendering HomeScreen");
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.activeOrders}>
          <OrdersList
            checkins={checkins}
            customChoiceItems={customChoiceItems}
            menuItemPrices={menuItemPrices}
            menuItems={menuItems}
            orders={orders}
            restaurantSlug={pickedRestaurant.slug}
            tables={tables}
            waitercalls={waitercalls}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.tableOvewView}>
          <TableOverview
            checkins={checkins}
            orders={orders}
            tables={tables}
            waitercalls={waitercalls}
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  checkins: getAllCheckinsSelector(state),
  customChoiceItems: getAllCustomChoiceItemsNormalizedSelector(state),
  menuItemPrices: getAllMenuItemPricesNormalizedSelector(state),
  menuItems: getAllMenuItemsNormalizedSelector(state),
  orders: getActiveOrdersSelector(state),
  pickedRestaurant: getPickedRestaurantSelector(state),
  tables: getAllTablesSelector(state),
  waitercalls: getAllActiveWaitercallsSelector(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

OrdersList (as you can see OrdersList also allows presses for orders, which displays the same erroneous behaviour of not having the TableOverView rerender), which is the left list with the clickable `<ListItem />`s.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { FlatList, Image, Text } from "react-native";
import { ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// ... omitted imports

export class OrdersList extends PureComponent {
  // omitted propTypes

  keyExtractor = item => item.uuid;

  registerItem = item => {
    // Remember the order status, in case the request fails.
    const { restaurantSlug, setOrders } = this.props;
    const itemStatus = item.orderStatus;
    const data = {
      restaurant_slug: restaurantSlug,
      order_status: "registered",
      order_uuid: item.uuid
    };

    setOrders({
      entities: { orders: { [item.uuid]: { ...item, orderStatus: data.order_status } } }
    });
    postOrderStatusCreate(data)
      .then(() => {})
      .catch(err => {
        // If the request fails, revert the order status change and display an alert!
        alert(err);
        setOrders({ entities: { orders: { [item.uuid]: { ...item, orderStatus: itemStatus } } } });
      });
  };

  answerWaitercall = item => {
    const { restaurantSlug, setWaitercalls } = this.props;
    const data = {
      done: true,
      restaurant_slug: restaurantSlug
    };
    setWaitercalls({ entities: { waitercalls: { [item.uuid]: { ...item, done: true } } } });
    putUpdateWaitercall(item.uuid, data)
      .then(() => {})
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err);
        setWaitercalls({ entities: { waitercalls: { [item.uuid]: { ...item, done: false } } } });
      });
  };

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const { checkins, customChoiceItems, menuItemPrices, menuItems, tables } = this.props;
    return item.menuItem ? (
      <ListItem
        title={`${item.amount}x ${menuItems[item.menuItem].name}`}
        leftElement={
          <Text style={styles.amount}>
            {tables.find(table => table.checkins.includes(item.checkin)).tableNumber}
          </Text>
        }
        rightTitle={`${
          menuItemPrices[item.menuItemPrice].label
            ? menuItemPrices[item.menuItemPrice].label
            : menuItemPrices[item.menuItemPrice].size
              ? menuItemPrices[item.menuItemPrice].size.size +
                menuItemPrices[item.menuItemPrice].size.unit
              : ""
        }`}
        subtitle={`${
          item.customChoiceItems.length > 0
            ? item.customChoiceItems.reduce((acc, customChoiceItem, index, arr) => {
                acc += customChoiceItems[customChoiceItem].name;
                acc += index < arr.length - 1 || item.wish ? "\n" : "";
                return acc;
              }, "")
            : null
        }${item.wish ? "\n" + item.wish : ""}`}
        onPress={() => this.registerItem(item)}
        containerStyle={styles.alignTop}
        bottomDivider={true}
      />
    ) : (
      <ListItem
        title={
          item.waitercallType === "bill"
            ? SCREEN_TEXT_HOME_BILL_CALLED
            : SCREEN_TEXT_HOME_SERVICE_ASKED
        }
        leftElement={
          <Text style={styles.amount}>
            {
              tables.find(table =>
                table.checkins.includes(
                  checkins.find(checkin => checkin.consumer === item.consumer).uuid
                )
              ).tableNumber
            }
          </Text>
        }
        rightIcon={{
          type: "ionicon",
          name: item.waitercallType === "bill" ? "logo-euro" : "ios-help-circle-outline"
        }}
        onPress={() => this.answerWaitercall(item)}
        bottomDivider={true}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { orders, waitercalls } = this.props;
    return (
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        data={[...orders, ...waitercalls]}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        // ... omitted ListHeader and ListEmpty properties
      />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { setOrders, setWaitercalls }
)(OrdersList);
```

TableOverview, which is the right `<FlatList />`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// ... omitted imports

export class TableOverview extends Component {
  // ... omitted propTypes

  keyExtractor = item => item.uuid;

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const { checkins, orders, waitercalls } = this.props;
    if (item.invisible) return <Table table={item} />;
    console.log("Rendering TableOverview");
    return (
      <Table
        table={item}
        hasActiveOrders={orders.some(order => item.userOrders.includes(order.uuid))}
        billWanted={item.checkins.some(checkin =>
          waitercalls.some(
            waitercall =>
              waitercall.waitercallType === "bill" &&
              waitercall.consumer ===
                checkins.find(checkinObj => checkinObj.uuid === checkin).consumer
          )
        )}
        serviceWanted={item.checkins.some(checkin =>
          waitercalls.some(
            waitercall =>
              waitercall.waitercallType === "waiter" &&
              waitercall.consumer ===
                checkins.find(checkinObj => checkinObj.uuid === checkin).consumer
          )
        )}
      />
    );
  };

  formatData = (data, numColumns) => {
    const numberOfFullRows = Math.floor(data.length / numColumns);

    let numberOfElementsLastRow = data.length - numberOfFullRows * numColumns;
    while (numberOfElementsLastRow !== numColumns && numberOfElementsLastRow !== 0) {
      data.push({ uuid: `blank-${numberOfElementsLastRow}`, invisible: true });
      numberOfElementsLastRow++;
    }

    return data;
  };

  render() {
    const { tables } = this.props;
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        data={this.formatData(tables, NUM_COLUMNS)}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        numColumns={NUM_COLUMNS}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default TableOverview;
```

Comment: You should know this is a very common problem in react application, use ComponentWillRecieveProps

Comment: @jsDevia I know it's a common problem and I was still unable to find a similar problem to mine, since the most common reason are direct mutations of state in the reducer, which is not the case in my reducer (at least I think so). `ComponentWillReceiveProps` is also deprecated which is why I would like to avoid using it.

Comment: Yes stop using ComponentWillReceiveProps. Are you using shouldComponentUpdate to prevent extra renderings?

Comment: I did not know componentWillReciveProps is deprecated. Let me find another solution.

Comment: @Think-Twice No I'm not using shouldComponentUpdate :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: @jsDevia  ComponentWillReceiveProps is deprecated. Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599656/can-getderivedstatefromprops-be-used-as-an-alternative-to-componentwillreceivepr

Comment: I think its deprecated in recent version of react. React version in my projects is 16, i need to change them.
tnx a lot.

Comment: @J.Hesters which is left list and right list. I am unable to see these in your code

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `<FlatList />`. Maybe I need to add something as the `extraData` prop for the `<FlatList />`?

Comment: @Think-Twice `<OrdersList />`. Also I edited the question to includes this information :)

Comment: ok the FlatList is not re-rendering when new props received? is that ur query

Comment: Found the solution, will post answer! Thank you for your engagement! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

The List was not rerendering, because the `<FlatList />` only looked at the tables and not the waitercalls.

I had to add the following property to the `<FlatList />`:

```
extraData={[...checkins, ...orders, ...waitercalls]}
```