# Mutating state in shouldComponentUpdate react 16.6.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Since react have deprecated many of their [`Lifecycle Methods`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) I found that, when using `redux` and `connect` when I want to augment local state of a `component` I am using `componentDidUpdate`. The problem is only `prevProps, prevState` are passed to this function.

That then means I only have `nextProps, nextState` inside the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifeCycle`.

To me this feels inherently wrong to do something as follows:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const { status_status } = nextProps;
    if(status_status === "error") {
      this.props.dispatch(resetStatus());
    }
    return true;
  }
```

This is surely an `antiPattern` and I should not be doing this.

How can I then get the `nextProps` without using `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: Why don't you use `componentDidUpdate`, It is supposed to handle such side effects . `componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { status } = this.props;
    if(status !== prevProps.status_status  && status === "error") {
      this.props.dispatch(resetStatus());
    }
  }`

Comment: ^ This looks like a solid answer IMHO.

Comment: Ahhh why but of course @ShubhamKhatri at this point `this.props` is the current state

Comment: @JamieHutber, nextProps will be currentProps after the render cycle and its perfectly fine and stable to call sideEffects after a state render than before it and that is why componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated

Comment: Thanks pal, if you could add this as the answer I'll accept it bud.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar case and I had found getDerivedStateFromProps useful and suitable in such condition.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  // now, you may dispatch checking the condition
  // BTW, you will dispatch just using props
  // props.dispatch()
  // this.props.dispatch() // invalid
}
```

I know this note from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use  componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.

But I am just sharing my experience that was only the case `getDerivedStateFromProps` working.

However, I would also suggest you to use `componentDidUpdate` hook first. And if everything seems good for you, then stick with it. Or if you also face using `componentDidUpdate` and feel alright using `getDerivedStateFromProps` then you may post your opinion and ideas as an answer.

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps is for updating state and all sideeffects are supposed to go in componentDidUpdate

Comment: Yeah, I was needed getDerivedStateFromProps must and nothing was working as expected. Just sharing my experience.

Comment: Although you can do it in getDerivedStateFromProps, but it isn't a right place to do such things as suggested in React docs too. ComponentDidUpdate is meant to be used for such things. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599656/can-getderivedstatefromprops-be-used-as-an-alternative-to-componentwillreceivepr/49599776#49599776